Sharing class member callback with other class
I have two classes, WebUiCoroutine and NADC338 (Worker). The NADC338 class handles some networking, after which I want it to "post" to the WebUiCoroutine class (which is written in header file). Essentially I want to pass/assign postHandler from WebUiCoroutine.h to postUpdate in NADC338 classdsdsdsdsdsdsd
I tried to pass the callback as seen below, and many other ways :/ This one fails with message '=': function as left operand
It's loosely based upon this question and many other Stack Overflow posts. I'm sure i have misunderstood/overlooked something essential.
WebUiCoroutine.h
class WebUiCoroutine {
    NADC338 nadAPI = NADC338("someIPAdress", port);
public: 
    WebUiCoroutine() {
        nadAPI.register_callback(std::bind(&WebUiCoroutine::postHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void postHandler(crow::json::wvalue) {
      //call another class member method of WebUiCoroutine
    }
}

NADC338.cpp
void NADC338::register_callback(std::function<void(crow::json::wvalue)> callback) {
    postUpdate = callback;
}

NADC338.h
class NADC338 {
    NADC338();
    NADC338(string ip, int port);

public:
    void (*postUpdate) (crow::json::wvalue);
    void register_callback(std::function<void(crow::json::wvalue)> callback);

}

Hope my problem is understandable and the code not too redacted.
Any input is appreciated

Why did you decide to use different types for postUpdate and callback in NADC338::register_callback?

"Hope [...] the code not too redacted." -- You don't need to rely on hope. Copy the code from your question and try compiling it as-is. If the first error message is "'=': function as left operand" then the code is not too redacted.

Callbacks are smth from C. Delegates are C++ preferred.

"Hope [...] the code not too redacted." -- I took a look, and my conclusion is that the code is not redacted enough. Drop WebUiCoroutine since that is not needed to produce the error. Drop the parameter because it is not needed and because its type (crow::json::wvalue) has no definition. Inline the function body for easier reading, and end up with #include <functional>
struct NADC338 {
void (*postUpdate) ();
void register_callback(std::function<void()> callback) {
postUpdate = callback;
}
}; Short, and too the point.

Thanks for the quick responses and help provided on my problem. It turned out an easy fix as pointed out by @SoronelHaetir. I just didnt have the understanding

@Rhaoama "It turned out an easy fix as pointed out by SoronelHaetir." -- That's not a surprise. I mean, no one suggested that the fix would be hard. In fact, the answer was so easy, I was hoping you would discover it yourself if prompted to explain your code (cf. rubber duck debugging) as part of improving your question. Then again, choosing to ignore all suggestions for improving your question is your prerogative.

Make PostUpdate a std::function rather than a direct function pointer.
It is not possible to cast an std::function when that std::function carries state (as yours must due to the binding).
Instead, make it:
std::function<void(crow::json::wvalue)> PostUpdate;

